# Which Silverlight Version Recommended for new development ASP.NET + GIS?

Tags: silverlight

I just started a new job where I need to do a new development in Silverlight technology. The existing application is an ASP.NET and GIS application.

What version of Silverlight is recommended to use?

I don't have any experience using Silverlight, please suggest me a good place to start -- Tutorials / Blogs/ resources...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS, then you should use Silverlight 4. The current version of the [Esri Silverlight SDK](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/) is [version 2.4](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=746). It is built on top of Silverlight 4. If you are using ArcGIS 10.1, then you can use [version 3.0](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=714). The current version (beta) of 3.0 is also built on Silverlight 4, but they were talking about building it on Silverlight 5.

Comment: UPDATE: Esri will build 3.0 on top of Silverlight 5 AND 4!

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 5 would be the best bet.  You can get lots of tutorials over at http://silverlight.net.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://silverlighttutorials.blogspot.in/),[this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/Silverlight-Tutorials.aspx) and [this](http://learn2codehere.blogspot.in/2012/03/silverlight-tutorials-introduction-to_05.html) are very good and knowledegeable for starters.

**[This](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)** shows many samples of the silverlight controls with source codes.
[This](http://nokola.com/) shows different practical uses of silverlight **with source codes!**

If you come across any other queries while development, you can post a question and get suggestions [here, on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) very easily.! :)